# Why isn't Word coming back to normal style after a Title?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I'm using Word from Office 365. In the previous versions, when I'm typing a title, then I press Enter, the police style comes back to Normal.

However :

[image: Word1]

Here it starts a new title, and when I try to erase the incrementation:
[image: word2]

It doesn't come back to Normal either. How do I get back to the old behaviour?

Comment: Can you check under the properties of your heading style that "Style for following paragraph" is set to "Normal"?

Comment: I can't seem to find the styles properties, and all I can find online refers to Word 2003.

Comment: Try the instructions on this page: http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/QandA2007.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

In order to modify a style, one has to click the bottom right-hand corner arrow of the Styles section, and in the flyer that appears, hover a style and click the downward arrow that appears, then `"Modify..."`.
An even simpler way is to right-click on the style in the Styles pane.

There I can finally find the `Style for following paragraph` and put it to `Normal` or whatever I want.